# Using command test with $_1/

Tags: bash, command-line, test

I'm trying to understand the command below, and particularly the parts that are in bold.

I understand what the second line is. It's testing if a file exists and if it doesn't, it creates one, but what does **`$_1/`** mean?

```
test "$1" = "0" && exit
test -f $_1/samplefile || touch $_1/samplefile
```

Comment: Depends if this is just a snippet. I saw a convention recently that _1, _2 etc were assigned with args to a function (or a whole script -- cant now recall). So the answer may lie somewhere else in the script, or as one-off exports on the command line that invoked it.

Comment: Sorry: to clarify: saw the construct: `_1=alpha _2=beta myCommand` with the intent that args to myCommand are in local environment, ordered but not positional, and are also global even within functions.

Answer (score 3):

`$_1` means "expand the variable `_1`". Since this variable was not set, it will expand to nothing. Someone probably made a mistake.

It may be that the person thought `$_1` would be the same as `${_}1`, i.e., the expansion of `$_`, ([which is the last argument to the previous command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)), concatenated with the number `1`. But it is not the same, as can be seen below:

```
$ cat tst.bash
#!/bin/bash
test "$1" = "0" && exit
echo $_
test "$1" = "0" && exit
echo $_1
test "$1" = "0" && exit
echo ${_}1
```

```
$ ./tst.bash
0

01
```

If you provide anything but the number 0 as an argument to the script (in the sample above, I provided no argument at all), then the `test` fails and `exit` is not triggered. So, for each `echo`, the last command executed is

```
test "$1" = "0"
```

, whose last argument is `0`. Thus, `$_` expands to `0`, `${_}1` expands to `01` and `$_1` expands to the empty string.

Comment: `$1` would be more sensible as part of the path since `$_` would always be `0` in the second line, like your sample script shows. It doesn't seem like a simple typo, though, since it appears twice and I don't think `_` is close to `1` or `$` on the common keyboard layouts..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I think that the person who wrote probably made a mistake. The propose was to check if there is a file and if not create a file. So, after some tries, I used `test -f $(pwd)”/samplefile” || touch samplefile` and it works. I just got confused because all commands are new for me, and I thought that maybe `$_1/` could mean something.
Thank you so much! :-)